# wordpress post search by multiple input fields

Tags: wordpress

There are two fields in form in `wordpress` to search the post table.

**How to override default `wordPress` search option to take more than one variable to search ?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post relevant code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why not create your own custom page and query posts based on your parameters ?